# How many items are shown in modern experience document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

We want to switch to modern experience in document library and change from having folders to just the items being there

How many items are shown and which files are shown in normal form if there are thousands of files in the document library  ?

How do you handle a lot of items in modern document library experience?
I used to use the navigation, views in the classic experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, there is a filter panel in sharepoint modern experience document library.You could use it to handle a lot of items.

The filters pane can help you find the file you’re looking for. When you make a filter selection, items that don’t match are removed from the list shown on the page.

References:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-the-list-and-library-filters-pane-293561ed-fb2e-4fb2-9a9f-8a21e299e323?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/differences-between-the-new-and-classic-experiences-for-lists-and-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite generic(theoretically) but I will try to answer it as per my knowledge .

**The Advantages of having a Modern library experience over a Classic are as below** -

1. Quicker editing of metadata with the information pane
2. Quickly update multiple documents’ metadata at once
3. Drag-and-drop from one group to another to update metadata
4. Ability to pin documents, links, and filters
5. Ability to move and copy documents and folders from the command bar
6. Better handling of required metadata
7. Creating and customizing views is easier
8. Allows you to set a per-item retention label
9. Custom column formatting only available in modern
10. You can upload a folder directly .

**For your question on how many files will get displayed on a modern experience**.

Well you can always change that using the item limit. Follow the steps below -

- Create a view
- In the view creation screen, scroll down to Item Limit section
- Choose the number of records you would like to display
- Make sure to choose  Limit the total number of items returned to the
  specified amount radio button

**For handling loads and loads of files you can use the following two techniques** -

1. Group by metadata
2. Filter by dynamic filters

**Scenarios for using Dynamic filters** -

- Filters tasks or issues assigned to the logged in user (Assigned To is equal to [Me])
- Filter for items or documents created or modified by the user who is
  logged in (Modified By is equal to [Me])
- Display items or documents that have expired (Expiration Date <
  [Today])